# Using asprintf inside another function to allocate Memory for String

Tags: mysql, c, memory-management, memory-leaks, printf

I'd like to know if this is good practice:

- getting a String from a database inside a function
- using asprintf to allocate memory for this String to be stored in a Struct that is passed to the function

I've already read several posts and articles about memory management and memory-leaks in C. In addition to that, I've read that it's not considered good to allocate memory inside a function, but how should I allocate memory in main, if I only know ho much to allocate when I'm inside the function, because the size of memory to be allocate depends on the length of the string from the database?

```
typedef struct{
    int age;
    char * name;
}my_struct;

bool get_data(my_struct * p){
    bool succes=false;

    if(mysql_real_connect(my, "localhost", SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, SQL_BASE, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"MYSQL-connection error!");
        success=false;
    }

    if(mysql_query(my, "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE id=1")){ // Assume this would be where the real data came from
        fprintf(stderr, "sql_query: %s\nfailed\n", query);
        success=false;
    }else{
        MYSQL_RES * result=NULL;
        result = mysql_store_result(my);

        if(mysql_num_rows(result) == 1){
            MYSQL_ROW row=NULL;
            row=mysql_fetch_row(result);
            p->age=atoi(row[1]);
            if(asprintf(&p->name, "%s", row[2])==-1){
                success=false;
                p->name=NULL;
            }else{
                success=true;
            }
        }else{
            success=false;
        }
        mysql_free_result(result);
    }

    mysql_close(my);
    return(success);
}

void init_my_struct(my_struct * s){
    s->age=0;
    s->name=""; // This should be: s->name=NULL;
}

void reset_my_struct(my_struct * s){
    if(s->name)free(s->name);
    init_my_struct(s);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    my_struct person;
    init_my_struct(&person);
    if(get_data(&person)){
        puts("OK");
    }else{
        puts("Not OK");
    }
    reset_my_struct(&person); // Frees memory if it was allocated
}
```

Also: I use own written functions to initialize and reset/detroy the struct `my_struct`, can this be considered safe? Or is it a ticking time bomb of memory corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to (m)allocate memory in a function. What the articles you read probably meant is that it is preferable to allocate memory before-hand and freeing it in the same function. But, as you discovered, this is only possible if the caller (`main` in your case) knows how much memory to allocate. In such cases I would recommend that you add a note to the documentation of the `get_data` function stating that it allocates memory in `p` which should be `free`d.

Having separate functions to initialize & destroy `struct`s is also perfectly fine. However, your `init_my_struct` function causes undefined behaviour in `reset_my_struct` because it assigns a(n empty) string constant `""` to the `name` member. If `reset_my_struct` would attempt to `free` this string it would result in undefined behaviour because even an empty string is not `NULL`/`0`/false. You should change that to:

```
s->name = NULL;
```

Finally, your use of `asprintf` is fine, but [`strdup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) is maybe more suited if you just want to duplicate the string without adding anything else. For example:

```
p->name = strdup(row[2]);
if(p->name == NULL){
    success=false;
}else{
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for these two (@Kninnug and @dbush) fast answers.
In my code I changed it to `s->name = NULL;` should I also change it in my Question, or should this serve as an example for others?

Comment: @Cdrmoi you should leave your question as-is so future visitors can learn from it. You can change the `rwo` typo though, since it's not relevant to the question :).

Answer (score 3):

This looks good except for one thing:

```
void init_my_struct(my_struct * s){
    s->age=0;
    s->name="";     // assigns a const char * to s->name
}
```

Here, you're setting `s->name` to a non-NULL value.  An empty string is not the same as NULL.  It is a single character array containing the value 0, i.e. a null terminated string with nothing before the null terminator.

If you attempted to `free(s->name)` before assigning anything to it, you'll likely core dump since the constant string `""` was not returned by `malloc`.

Allocating memory inside a function is fine, particularly if figuring out how much memory is needed is a task left to the function.  But you have to make sure to `free` it at some point after the function call.

Comment: could I also do this in main:
`my_struct * person=calloc(1, sizeof(my_struct));`
`//Do something`
`free(person); //to free all memory consumed by person`
Or do I need to free each member (in the full Program there are more strings) of `my_struct`?

Comment: @Cdrmoi You can do that, however that just allocates memory for the struct itself, not for anything its members point to.  You would still have to malloc/free any pointers contained within the struct.